# Obtaining a list of supported operations for a WorkItemType's FieldDefinition or Field in TFS in C#

Tags: c#, tfs

Notes:

-By supported operations I mean things like "equals", "contains", "was ever".

-I'm using the TFS 2013 C# APIs.

We're trying to create a query editor. I can get a WorkItemType and from that, FieldDefinitions. Or I can get a WorkItem and its [Fields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Field);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true). However these objects don't contain lists of supported operations.

The reason I think this might exist somewhere else in this API is because the 2015 REST APIs' Work Item Fields contain [supportedOperations](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/wit/fields). However we can't use those REST APIs because their work item data doesn't contain allowable values.

My question is whether or not there is any way to get these supported operations via the TFS 2013 C# APIs. I've done much searching the the API's surface area is huge so I figured I'd ask. Thanks!

Comment: Why you want to get operators via API. Table in my reply below shows the available operators.

Comment: Different fields support different sets of operators. It is convenient and robust to get the set of supported operators for each field via the API. From the link you posted below, it sounds like we could programmatically determine the set of supported operators for a field based on the fields' properties. However since we need to take into account a field's data type, whether it's indexed or not, and the type of database deployment used, it's more error-prone :)

Comment: The operator should be associated with field type. However, I can't figure out you the API for it. How about you create one enum type to list all the supported operators for all field types, and then use the enum in your code? The operator and filed type mapping relationships can be fount in my reply below.

Answer (score 0):

This table below lists the available operators, and also the Applicable data types:

[image]

Check this MSDN article for the details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286638.aspx